# Sorting TreeView nodes

Tags: vb.net, winforms, sorting, treeview

I have problem in sorting TreeView nodes. I tried the example as found on MSDN [TreeView won't sort properly](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e99c9fd8-5dff-42cc-bd62-30afe81f35f9/vbnet-2005-treeview-wont-sort-properly?forum=winforms) by **blitzy** on "*Monday, February 26, 2007 2:37 PM*" and made some modification on **NodeSortClick** as below:

```vb
Dim SortThis As New List(Of String)

If lblSort.Text = "Unsorted" Then
    lblSort.Text = "Sorted"
    ResultTree.TreeViewNodeSorter = New NodeSorter("Ascending")
    ResultTree.Sort()
Else
    'ResultTree.TreeViewNodeSorter = Nothing
    'ResultTree.Sort()
    ResultTree.TreeViewNodeSorter = New NodeSorter("Descending")
    ResultTree.Sort()
    lblSort.Text = "Unsorted"
End If
```

The problem is it did sort in by length, however when I try to click sort again, it wont be able to sort anymore. It also doesn't able to remove the sorting.

What I want is to sort the TreeViww nodes by alphabetically order by ascending, descending and removing the sort. Anyone able to help me? Can either refer me to VB.NET sample I can explore on or helping in the script.

I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Clearing the items in the TreeView and adding them back should remove the sorting.

Comment: are you referring to treeview.Nodes.clear.? it would remove my records in the tree and even so, when i try reinsert the record again, it will still be sorted probably because of the Treeview.Sort()

Comment: No problem for the sorting alphabetically part, you could create a sorter class that implements the `IComparer(Of TreeNode)` interface and compare the string using the [String.CompareOrdinal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compareordinal?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.String.CompareOrdinal);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netcore-3.1) method.

Comment: For the undo the sort part, you need to keep track of the sorted nodes and the original order of the child nodes  so you can revert.

Comment: How do i keep track of the original order in order to return to it original stage ?

Comment: Maybe `Dictionary(Of String, List(Of Integer))` where the key is the node name and the value is the indices  of the children BEFORE you sort their parent node. Then to undo, find the node using the `Find` method and reorder the children. I have to say that undoing the sort is odd requirement. Maybe you mean an option to prevent the sorting  when you populate the TreeView? Not sure about what you are tying to achieve here. Your code is just to sort the nodes in ascending and descending orders. nothing about _unsort_. If that is what you need then it will be an easy task.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.treeviewnodesorter?view=netcore-3.1) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.sort?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.TreeView.Sort);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netcore-3.1#remarks) would help to decide.?